# If 7 or more days past html date and if not paid change the innerHTML using only vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, momentjs, innerhtml

If I have the following hard coded HTML date:

```
<h2 id="date">17/02/2018</h2>
<h2 id="status">Not paid</h2>
```

With a deadline being the h2 date plus 1 week or more.

How would I write javascript so that if the deadline is gone and the h2 status is not paid then how would I change the `<h2 id="status">Not paid</h2>`
 to display the text `overdue` instead of `Not paid`

I tried getting the current date then adding 7 days by using moment.js:
 `moment().format('L').add(7, 'days');` since it gives me the same date format (`dd/mm/yyyy`) then comparing it to the h2 date but the problem is since moment.js will always get **today's date** and add 7 days to it so it will always be 7 days in the future. Not 7 days from the h2 date.

A seemingly simple problem which I have been stuck with for 2 days.

Comment: You need to select the contents of your element into your `moment` date.  `let myDate = document.getElementById('date').innerText`, for example. You should probably validate that date text too, but in the most basic sense, that's how you can get the contents of the element with `id` of "date".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get access to the date first, by pulling the text from the date element:

```
let myDate = document.getElementById('date').innerText;
```

Then, you can use moment to instantiate that as a moment date (assuming it's in a valid format):

```
let momentDate = moment(myDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
```

Now you can work with `momentDate` by adding days to it, comparing it to other dates, etc., e.g.:

```
let oneWeekLater = momentDate.add(7, 'days');
```

If you want to change the value of the "status" element, you can then do something like:

```
let statusElement = document.getElementById("status");
statusElement.innerText = "Thank you for paying!";
```

Comment: Thanks but I tried something similar but like I said in the post simply adding days to moment js won't work because it adds the days onto **today** rather than the HTML date.

Comment: Once you have a `momentDate`, just do `momentDate.add(7, 'days')`.  Your problem is that `moment()` by itself returns today's date, and you're adding 7 days to that.

Answer (score 0):

Heres the solution:

```
const currentStatus = document.getElementById('status').innerText;

let myDate = document.getElementById('date').innerText;
//get the date in the html
// 100% correct

let momentDate = moment(myDate, "DD/MM/YYYY");
// gets the myDate variable and converts it into soemthing JS can understand
// 100% correct

let oneWeekLater = momentDate.add(7, 'days').format("YYYY/MM/DD");
// Need to comapare the dates based on bigest number first which is the year then 
month etc... it then adds one week on to it


let today =  moment(new Date()).format("YYYY/MM/DD");
// prints out todays date in the same format as oneWeekLater so they cna be compared

if(currentStatus.innerText == "Up-paid"){
  if (oneWeekLater >= today){
    document.write('Overdue')
  } else{
    document.write('not paid')
  }
} else {
  currentStatus.innerText = "Thank you for paying"
}
```

Comment: It looks like my generalized answer got you to your specific solution.  I suggest marking it correct.

Comment: Yeah, you definitely sent me in the right direction, thank you!

Comment: Great!  If you mark the checkbox next to the answer, that'll register it as the accepted solution.

Comment: for some reason, It says "you can accept your own answer tomorrow " so I guess I'll wait till tomorrow

Comment: Right, but presumably you can accept my answer today.  That's what I'm getting it.